Is there a non-commutative ring with unity $R$ such that its Jacobson radical is not a two-sided maximal ideal?
In the realm of commutative rings, it is well-understood that the Jacobson radical need not be a maximal ideal, as demonstrated by the ring $R = \mathbb{Z} $.
Does this principle also apply to non-commutative rings? Specifically, is there an example of a non-commutative ring with unity $R$ in which its Jacobson radical is not a two-sided maximal ideal?
Let $k$ be a field. The following matrix provides a counterexample:
\begin{pmatrix}
k & k \\
0 & k
\end{pmatrix}
Are there other counterexamples available?

It sounds a little bit like you're thinking of noncommutative rings and commutative rings as disjoint classes, whereas the prevailing viewpoint is that commutative rings are a subclass of "(possibly) noncommutative rings"

The Jacobson radical is not often maximal, because $R/J(R)$ does not have to be a simple ring.
It would seem you have answered your own question already, because your example is fine.
Given any two nonzero rings $R,S$ at all, the Jacobson radical of $R\times S$ will not be maximal.
Or, for example, any semiprimitive ring that is not simple.

DaRT query for rings that are "not top simple" meaning that $R/J(R)$ is not a simple ring.

Good idea! Thank you for sharing the information with me.
